# Indexing pandas dataframe by passing a list

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I am trying to select multiple values from a DataFrame object that looks like this:

```
Int64Index: 100 entries, 0 to 99
Data columns (total 6 columns):
Cell                  68  non-null values
Sequence Protocol     68  non-null values
dtypes: float64(2), object(4)
```

I would like to select multiple values based on the value in the Cell column. I know how to do this by running a for loop over the data but I find that clunky.

Ideally, I would like to pass a list of "cells" that would give me another DataFrame object back.

An example output would be following:

```
idx = cell_info.Cell == ['1','3','5']
```

Would give the following for `idx`:

```
0    True
1   False
2    True
3   False
4    True
5   False
6   False
...
```

With `np.sum(idx)` would equal to `3`

I have tried reindexing by Cell:

```
cell_info.reindex(index=cell_info.Cell)
```

Which results in empty DataFrame.

I tried passing the following to get the indexes where data.keys() is a list of cells I want to index by:

```
idx = cell_info.Cell == data.keys()
```

Which results in all values False i.e `np.sum(idx)` will yield `0` (but doesn't if I call each of them on its own).

If I do the following:

```
np.where(cell_info.Cell == data.keys())
```

It returns empty array, however, if I do the following:

```
np.where(cell_info.Cell == list(data.keys()))
```

It gives an error:

```
ValueError: Arrays were different lengths: 100 vs 19
```

It would be great if you could explain what is the appropriate way of passing a list to index and why there is a difference in the last two calls.

Comment: Edit your question to include the actual data in `cell_info` and what your desired result is. If you can't share the data in cell_info make a small example that demonstrates the problem. As a guess I think that the `query` or `isin` methods are what you're looking for, but I can't say for sure without an example.

Comment: Yes `isin` method works beautifully. Why don't you put it as your answer and I will accept it. Thanks a lot, I knew it had to be something obvious I was missing!